# run a while loop untill a css selector is present on web page

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I need to run this loop until ".loadMore" css selector is present on webpage:

```
while ec.presence_of_element_located('.loadMore'):
        element_number = 25 * i
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, time1);
        sub_button = (by, hook + str(element_number))
        wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(sub_button))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(button).click()
        time.sleep(5)  # Makes the page wait for the element to change
        i += 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't an implicit wait work better in this situation?

Comment: I need the while condition. In other word run the loop untill .loadMore is present in web page

Comment: The implicit wait would take the place of the wait you already have, is my point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your def to check for element presence

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException        
def check_element_presence(selector):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

Now run it like

```
while check_element_presence('.loadmore'):
   ...
   ...
   ...
```